# getAccountsByType("com.google") fails to list my Google Account for minSdkVersion 21 and targetSdkVersion 27

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/identify) I am trying to get the `Google Account` on my `Nexus` phone:

```
val am: AccountManager = AccountManager.get(this)
val myAccounts: Array<Account> = am.getAccountsByType("com.google")
```

Even though I definitely have an account and can see logs refering to it such as `I/TrustAgent: [HomeAddressChangeTracker] fetch for account myaddress@gmail.com` AND I have added the permissions and verified they are granted, the array is always empty.

I have `minSdkVersion 21` and `targetSdkVersion 27`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [changes in 8.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#aaad), accounts aren't accessible just with the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission. You also need to require the user to choose an account using [`AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#newChooseAccountIntent(android.accounts.Account,%20java.util.List%3Candroid.accounts.Account%3E,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.os.Bundle)) like so:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        val intent = AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, arrayOf("com.google"), null, null, null, null)
        startActivityForResult(intent, 42)
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    if (requestCode == 42) 
        val accountManager = AccountManager.get(this)
        val accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google")
        accounts.forEach {
            Log.v(localClassName, it.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

As noted in the documentation for `AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent`:

> Chosen account is marked as VISIBILITY_USER_MANAGED_VISIBLE to the caller (see setAccountVisibility(Account, String, int)) and will be returned to it in consequent getAccountsByType(String)) calls.

so you should only have to choose the account once, and then the system should remember this choice for subsequent calls to `AccountManager.getAccountsByType`.